# Data manipulations in column-based SQL tables

Tags: sql-server, database

I need a fast and reliable solution for manipulating data in a column-based database. The database will store simulation data with 1 million values for each variable, so a table (or tables) will always be with 1 million rows.

I need a solution that will allow really fast:

1. saving of 1 million values into the table (or a column), e.g. Var1, Var2, etc..
2. update of a table with 1 million new values (existing million values replaced by new values)
3. calculated columns, e.g. Var1 + Var2 , or Var1 * (1 + Var2), etc.

I have tried MS SQL things like:

```
SELECT * INTO <VarTable> FROM <CLR Table-Valued Function>
```

And then

```
UPDATE <VarTable> SET <Var1> = <NewVar> FROM <TempTable> WHERE VarTable.ID = TempTable.ID
```

But the above works very slowly as there are a million rows in each column. 
I need a solution that allows quick replacement of whole columns and fast simple mathematical operations between the columns (or tables if the columns are in different tables) with the assumption that all columns will always have the same number of rows (1 million).

Comment: If I read this right, it seems like a poor fit for SQL Server, with generic large volumes of data that have to change so quickly - have you considered some other technology? Does this have to be accomplished with SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server was just the first option I wanted to try because of its popularity. I am open to any suggestions that would allow the above given that the data storage needs to allow multiple simultaneous connections.

Comment: How much resiliency do you need? Part of the speed-of-changes issue is that SQL Server uses write-ahead logging and commits work to disk in order to safeguard it against any and all failures (hardware / OS crash, etc.) What are the implications in your scenario if, for example, everything were just in memory instead?

Comment: Example - when I think about putting speed first in a problem like this, I go right to wanting direct pointers between objects residing in memory, rather than what an RDBMS does, which is to search using indexes (e.g. btrees) and try to safeguard everything with stable media.

Comment: That said, you might want to look at SQL Server in-memory OLTP and see if it fits - it's mostly about accelerating small-scope transactions, though, not changing 1 mil rows at a time. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133186.aspx